# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2), simple pandas code

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, boxplot

My goal is it to compare my six lists of values (SAM_x1 to SAM_x6) using boxplots and violin plots. That worked so far. Now I'd like to have the units of the x-axis to be named according to the list's names ie. SAM_x1 to SAM_x6.
As of now, the x-axis counts the columns from 0-5:
[image: Output]

Here is my code, I added columns to the dataframe expression, but I get an error stating there are too many values to unpack.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb

data = pd.read_csv("performance_tests.csv", skiprows=2)
    
SAM_x1 = data.iloc[0:191, 2].tolist()
SAM_x2 = data.iloc[0:191, 4].tolist()
SAM_x3 = data.iloc[0:191, 6].tolist()
SAM_x4 = data.iloc[0:191, 8].tolist()
SAM_x5 = data.iloc[0:191, 10].tolist()
SAM_x6 = data.iloc[0:191, 12].tolist()

df = pd.DataFrame([SAM_x1, SAM_x2, SAM_x3, SAM_x4, SAM_x5, SAM_x6]).T, columns=['SAM_x1', 'SAM_x2', 'SAM_x3', 'SAM_x4', 'SAMx_5', 'SAM_x6']

df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)

df.boxplot() 

sb.violinplot(data = df)
```

Comment: Look at the parentheses in `df = pd.DataFrame([SAM_x1, SAM_x2, SAM_x3, SAM_x4, SAM_x5, SAM_x6])...`

Comment: unfortunately it does not work that way. The lists are now rows instead of columns and I get the error: ValueError: 6 columns passed, passed data had 191 columns

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([SAM_x1, SAM_x2, SAM_x3, SAM_x4, SAM_x5, SAM_x6], columns=['SAM_x1', 'SAM_x2', 'SAM_x3', 'SAM_x4', 'SAMx_5', 'SAM_x6']).T
```